# Return openmp threads to single thread after finishing

Tags: c, macos, openmp

I use `openmp` to parallel a specific region in my C code:

```
#pragma omp parallel private()
{

...

}
```

When I check the process (via Activity Monitor in Mac OS X), I notice the number of threads is not returned back to 1 after exiting the `#pragma` block. Do I need to write something to return the process to be on a single thread after finishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most OpenMP implementations make use of thread pools. Threads are not destroyed but rather put to sleep and awaken when there is a new parallel region where they are needed. This is done both for the sake of efficiency, e.g, that way the overhead of creating new parallel regions is reduced, and for conformity to the OpenMP specification regarding the lifetime and accessibility of thread-private variables.

Comment: ... and to respond directly to the question, OpenMP does not provide a mechanism by which you can instruct it to reduce the live thread count.  As this answer explains, however, for all intents and purposes, it is a non-issue.